# How to select all from one table order by the last created timestamp of values from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables called `conversation` and `message`.

I would like to select all conversations sorted by order of the last updated message related to the conversation. The conversation table doesn't have the updated_at and to be able to get all conversations ordered by the last updated_at, that should be deducted from the last created message in the conversation from the table message.

The result should be based on what is the last message of the conversation.

The SQL I tried is not giving me the right result and I believe I should use a join but as I'm new to SQL cannot really get it how

```
select
    *
from
    conversation
inner join message on
    conversation.id = message.conversation_id
order by
    message.updated_at desc;
```

Tables looks as follow

The conversation

| id | topic | origin_type | origin_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | t1 | doc1 | xx1 | 2021-04-07 13:23:40 |
| 2 | t2 | doc2 | xx2 | 2021-04-07 14:23:40 |
| 3 | t3 | doc3 | xx3 | 2021-04-07 15:23:40 |

Message table

| id | conversation_id | message | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | xxx | 2021-04-07 13:23:40 | 2021-04-07 13:23:40 |
| 2 | 2 | xxx | 2021-04-07 14:23:40 | 2021-04-07 14:23:40 |
| 3 | 3 | xxx | 2021-04-07 15:23:40 | 2021-04-07 15:23:40 |

Seeing the tables I should get a result of the select as follow I believe as the
conversation.id = 3 has the last created and most recent message.

| id | conversation_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |

In SQL/PSQL I don't know how to do this kind of selection

Comment: If you expect that your messaging app will be used by large number of people, it will be better to keep this data in `conversation` table in order not to read all the conversions to sort them later or all the messages to find the latest per conversation (moreover, each conversation includes multiple people but the same latest message).

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion but I have specifics which obligate me to keep in this specific way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is not particularly illustrative, because the conversations only have a single message.  However, I think you want to keep all rows for a conversation together.  That would use a window function to get the maximum updated time for each conversation:

```
order by max(message.updated_at) over (partition by conversation.id) desc,
         conversation.id,
         message.updated_at desc
```

EDIT:

If you just want the *conversations* with no message information, you can use a subquery:

```
select c.*
from conversations c
order by (select max(m.updated_at) from messages m where m.conversation_id = c.id) desc;
```

Comment: For keep simple I put one message but yes should be more as every conversation can have many messages but the topic doesn't change. I will give a try of your suggestion.

Comment: I tried but the result is not right I'm getting like 1111, 2222, 33333333, 444444444 and so on I should get back just the conversations order by without the messages and duplicates in the result. Like I shared before like 1 2 3 4 and so on order by the last created at or updated at message of the conversation

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a scalar subquery:

```
select *,
    (
        select max(m.updated_at) from message m
        where m.conversation_id = c.conversation_id
    ) as last_updated_at
from conversation c
order by last_updated_at desc;
```